# how to get private methods of a child by calling get_class_methods within the parent class

Tags: php, oop

I'm wondering if there's a way to get this working:

```
<?php 
    class Foo
    {
        public function getMethods()
        {
            $methods = get_class_methods($this);
            print_r($methods);
        }
    }

    class Bar extends Foo
    {
        private function privateFunction() {}   // Not visible for parent::getMethods()
    }

    $Bar = new Bar();
    $Bar->getMethods();
?>
```

There's a parent class Foo, in which I've a method calling the get_class_methods($this)-Function. I'll always extend the Foo-Class by several different Bar-Classes. My problem is, that I can't see the private method privateFunction().
 The goal for me would be, to see all methods of Bar but I don't want to recreate the getMethods()-Method within each of the child-classes. 
So is there a way to get them within the parent-Class, or do I have to overwrite the getMethods()-Method in each child-class?

Comment: What about protected instead of private ?

Comment: @Random that would work yes, but it would mean i've to edit all existing child-classes and i cant make methods private for child-child-classes

Comment: I think you'll have to either overload the parent method, either redefine private methods of all childs... the problem is the private keyword that force you to do you one of these 2 solutions... private is VERY restrictive...

Comment: You probably need to use Reflection for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) for this

```
class Foo {
    public function getMethods() {
        $class = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $methods = $class->getMethods(
            ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC | 
            ReflectionMethod::IS_PROTECTED | 
            ReflectionMethod::IS_PRIVATE
        );
        print_r($methods);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function privateFunction() {}
}

$Bar = new Bar();
$Bar->getMethods();
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/2dBIV)

Comment: That's working great for me. The plus is, that i also can filter the methods-list to only the ones of the child-class. The methods of the parent aren't need for what I want to do. Thanks!